# Custom select query wordpress order by meta key value

Tags: php, wordpress

I am trying to `ORDER BY` my results of a custom select query.

But I am trying to order by the value of a meta key.

Please see my query below...

```
$get_atts =  $wpdb->get_results("SELECT ID, post_title FROM $wpdb->posts WHERE $wpdb->posts.post_type IN ('individual') ORDER BY $wpdb->posts.meta_key = 'surname' ASC");
```

As you can see this `ORDER BY` is breaking it...

```
ORDER BY $wpdb->posts.meta_key = 'surname' ASC"
```

So I am trying to order by the value of `surname`

But my does not seem to work. Can any explain why or help?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Try to use this query:

```
$get_atts =  $wpdb->get_results("SELECT ID, post_title FROM $wpdb->posts, $wpdb->postmeta
    WHERE $wpdb->posts.ID = $wpdb->postmeta.post_id AND $wpdb->postmeta.meta_key = 'surname' 
    AND $wpdb->posts.post_type IN ('individual') ORDER BY $wpdb->postmeta.meta_value ASC");
```